# Xamarin.Forms app bug when re-open page using Prism

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism

I've been working for a loteria aplication (mexican game), the bug consists that when I reopen the page the UI does not responds to the viewModel actions. I'm using Prism.Unity.Forms, the application uses concepts such as Device.StartTimer() for every x time pick randomly the card of the deck, other thing that my app uses is MessagingCenter for sending messages from the ViewModel to the View for updating the board of the user (changing the background color of the imageButton that contains the card in which the user pick), and I suppose one of those things are giving me the "bug", finally **important fact**: when I leave the page, the app takes more time to go again to the page and execute the logic related to its viewmodel,  does anyone can guide me through knowing what problem do I'm facing?

Comment: sounds like you have a memory leak... which is really not shocking if you're using the Device.StartTimer and MessagingCenter....since you don't have a sample here it's really hard to say anything with certainty

Comment: @DanSiegel thanks! I don’t have allowed to share te code but I have a question, why these 2 concepts (Device.StartTimer and MessagingCenter) produce a memory leak? What’s the problem? (Behind of the code I used, just want to know in general situations)

Comment: When you're encouraged to share code this does not mean share your original source. It's a good practice to try to reproduce the issue in a sharable sample when you run into problems. The simplification often helps to resolve issues. As for your question, the problem is that people typically forget to unsubscribe properly thus causing a memory leak.

Comment: @DanSiegel what do you mean by unsubscribing properly?